# How to save scraping data into csv file when using selenium and multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape product name price and current time for many urls with selenium. And i append the name, price and time into three different lists, put them into dictionary and then save into csv file. To increase the speed of scraping, i also use threading to scrape multiple pages at the same time.

However, after using ThreadPoolExecutor, the name of the scraped products and just mismatch its price in output file. It will match with other products' price. I guess it is because the order of scraping changed because the time of loading pages when scraping is different so the name and price in two list cannot match. What should I do to match the name with its price? Any help appreciates. Thanks

```
        urlList =  [https://www.target.com/p/systane-gel-drops-lubricant-eye-gel-0-33- 
        fl- oz/-/A-14523072#lnk=sametab,
        ...
        ...]
        priceArray = []
        nameArray = []
        GMTArray = []
        
        def ScrapingTarget(url):
            wait_imp = 10
            CO = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            CO.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
            CO.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            CO.add_argument('--start-maximized')
            wd = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32new\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe',options=CO)
            wd.get(url)
            wd.implicitly_wait(wait_imp)
            #start scraping
            name = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span").text
            nameArray.append(name)
            price = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='pageBodyContainer']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
            priceArray.append(price)
            tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
            GMT = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            GMTArray.append(GMT)
        
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
            executor.map(ScrapingTarget, urlList)
        
        data = {'prod-name': nameArray,
                'Price': priceArray,
                "GMT": GMTArray
                }
        #df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['prod-name', 'Price','currentZipCode',"Tcin","UPC","GMT"])
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
        df = df.transpose()
        df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\12987\PycharmProjects\python\Network\priceingAlgoriCoding\export_Target_dataframe.csv', mode='a', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: seems like you'd need separate arrays, csv files, pandas for each thread.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the comment, can you talk more about how to separate arrays? It really confused me. I still did not find a good way to do that.

Comment: I don't know Python, so I can't get too specific, but you'd want to pass in references to new arrays (or classes) for each thread.  Then let the thread create each csv.  If you just put all properties/methods in a class with a constructor that should be all you need for each thread.